# C# WPF Keep dialog (child) window open if input is wrong

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, dialog, dialogresult

I am looking for a solution to not close my dialog window when there is a duplicate ID. I guess it has to do with `DialogResult`, however, I cannot make neither `true` or `false` work.

I am opening the "New Store"-window from a button click in my main window.

```
NewStoreWindow newStore = new NewStoreWindow();
newStore.ShowDialog();
```

As you can see on the screenshots below, you can fill in the ID and the Name. I have successfully made an input validation, so you cannot press "OK" when the 2 textboxes are empty.

[image: App]

When you press "OK" and the ID is already in my `listview` (`gridview`), it will give the user the below error message. However, it will also close the "New Store"-window. As said, I would like that the window is kept open until it successfully is added, so that the user can just edit the ID instead of having to open the "New Store"-window again and typing it again.
It should only close the window when it is successfully added or `cancel`/X is pressed.
I have tried to play around with `closing`-event for "New Store", but it does not seem to work.

[image: Error message]

Is this just the designed behavior? And is there a way to bypass/work around it?

**CS**

```
public partial class NewStoreWindow : Window
        {

        public static bool itemAlreadyAdded;
        //public MainWindow mainWin = new MainWindow();

        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

        public NewStoreWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //SetButtonState();
        }

        // Data Binding
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SidProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Sid", typeof(string), typeof(NewStoreWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(String.Empty));
        public string Sid
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SidProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SidProperty, value); }
        }

        // Data Binding
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SName", typeof(string), typeof(NewStoreWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(String.Empty));
        public string SName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SNameProperty, value); }
        }

private void cmdOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            DialogResult = true;

            MainWindow mainWin = new MainWindow();

            // Check if any items exist in listview
            if (MainWindow._list.Count == 0)
            {
                MainWindow._list.Add(new MainWindow.Data() { Sid = Sid, SName = SName });
            }
            else // items exist
            {
                itemAlreadyAdded = false; // use for boolean checking
                foreach (var item in mainWin.lvStores.Items.OfType<MainWindow.Data>()) // loop through all items in listview
                {


                    if (item.Sid == Sid) // Check if new item already exists
                    {
                        itemAlreadyAdded = true;
                    }

                    if (itemAlreadyAdded) // Show messagebox if it exists
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("ID needs to be unique, please respecify!", "Duplicate ID",
                            MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!itemAlreadyAdded) // If it does not already exist, add it
                {
                    // if it does not exist, create it from the textbox values
                    MainWindow._list.Add(new MainWindow.Data() { Sid = Sid, SName = SName });

                    // Refresh listview
                    mainWin.lvStores.Items.Refresh();
                   // Close Window
                   Close();
                }
            }  
        }

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();

}

public void Close()
{
    this.Closing -= Window_Closing;
    base.Close();
}
```

Comment: where is you code for the Ok button event the window should not close itself unless you are telling it to close when you click OK

Comment: @user5195490 updated with code now. I do not have the `Closing` in my XAML, because it will not work properly. The SName will not get read from the `textbox`, when I do so.

Comment: Why are you calling this.Hide() in the Window_Closing event handler?

Comment: @mm8 to see if I could keep the values there. But it doesn't matter if I have it there or not.